# Find first occurence of a sequence in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table looking like this

```
  NAME     DATE
  --------------------
   A       2014.01.01
   A       2014.01.02
   B       2014.01.05
   B       2014.01.06
   B       2014.01.07
   C       2014.01.08
   C       2014.01.10
   C       2014.01.11
   B       2014.01.13
   B       2014.01.15
   B       2014.01.18
```

How can I extract the first occurrence of each 'NAME' sequence?

Meaning I would like to have the following returned:

```
NAME     DATE
 A       2014.01.01
 B       2014.01.05
 C       2014.01.08
 B       2014.01.13
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `min()`:

```
select name, min(date) as date
from table t
group by name;
```

Comment: In this case, it would yield a single result for 'B'. I'm looking for the first (or minimum) result for each **group** of NAME.

Comment: @PhilippePinsonneault . . . Your question only references two columns.  So, the first/minimum results is provided by the `min()` function.  If you have a different question, then *ask* a new question.  Editing this one is likely to invalidate the answers that are here, which can attract downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

A basic `group by` and use of the `MIN` function should do it:

```
SELECT NAME, MIN(DATE) FROM Table GROUP BY NAME
```

SQL Server provides a [number of different aggregate functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) that allow you to do this type of thing.

Comment: Using MIN(DATE) would only yield one result for NAME='B'. Yet I need to results, one, for each group of consecutive 'B' values.